# angularjs form, input value changed programmatic(by code) not submitted to controller

Tags: angularjs, input

my problem is that after change input value by code or any plugin new value not submitted to controller and old value of property is accessible.
but if change input value by typing new value is available! only by typing!
template :

```
 <input class="form-control" id="ng-taskLineBackColor" 
       type="text" ng-model="data.preference.lineBackColor"/>

 <input type="submit" ng-click="update()"  class="btn btn-primary" value="save"/>
```

controller :

```
.controller('taskCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

        $scope.getRef = function () {
            return //any code
        };
        $scope.save = function () {
             var newValue = $scope.data.preference.lineBackColor;
             //!!!-->newValue Contain old Value

        };
    }])
```

Answer (score 6):

Any code which changes the value of ng-taskLineBackColor needs to trigger a special event called "input".  This will notify AngularJS

```
$(function() {
    $('#ng-taskLineBackColor').val('new value').trigger('input');
});
```

Comment: Does this behavior really exists in Angular? A.K.A. is it documented?

Answer (score 2):

To do this only with jQlite and without jQuery try:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#ng-taskLineBackColor')).triggerHand‌​ler('input')
```

And here's the API you have available on an `angular.element`-wrapped HTML element:

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Answer (score 0):

I create working JSfiddle for your case.

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/2344/)

```
 <input class="form-control" id="ng-taskLineBackColor" 
       type="text" ng-model="data.preference.lineBackColor"/>
 <input type="submit" ng-click="update()"  class="btn btn-primary" value="save"/>
```

I renamed function "save", declared in controller on "update".

**UPDATE:**

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.update = function () {
        var value = $scope.data.preference.lineBackColor;
        alert("Typing value = '" + value + "'");
        $scope.data.preference.lineBackColor = "Value from code";
        var newValue = $scope.data.preference.lineBackColor;
        alert("Typing value = '" + newValue + "'");
    };
}
```

Comment: no!my condition is that value **modified by code**.for time typing value there is no problem.

Comment: thanks for your trying but pay attention to this subject: modify programaticall(by code) **html element value** you modify property of object!.in this sample change input value by any code or plug in then get new value!thanks

Comment: @sajjad, what you mean under "**html element value**"? Value, which shows in input?

Comment: yes. ok!  for this sample html element value is value of input text type.

Comment: @sajjad, in my JSfiddle example, I change value of input text at controller. 
$scope.data.preference.lineBackColor = "Value from code";

After that, you will see new text-value in input.